# UNIT TEST TRIGGER - Coverage Test Trigger and using System.assertEquals

Tags: trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

[image]

Hello, I'm new to salesforce and I have a problem with test coverage and System.assertEquals

1. My coverage is insufficient
2. And I get this as an error:

Errors :
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: ZCleadtest01, Actual: Test Lead1
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: ZCleadtest02, Actual: Test Lead2
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: ZCleadtest03, Actual: Test Lead3

Stack Trace :
Class.AffectationLeadBefore_TEST.testLeadTriggerViaDML1: line 104, column 1
Class.AffectationLeadBefore_TEST.testLeadTriggerViaDML2: line 116, column 1
Class.AffectationLeadBefore_TEST.testLeadTriggerViaDML3: line 127, column 1

Trigger

```
trigger AffectationLeadBefore on Lead (before insert) {

   
if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) {

    List<String> zipcodes = new List<String>();
    List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
 
   
    for (Lead record : Trigger.new) {

        if (record.PostalCode != null) {

            zipcodes.add(record.PostalCode);
                           
        }
    }

        List<Zip_Code__c> codes = [SELECT Name, Franchise_area__c FROM Zip_Code__c WHERE Name IN :zipcodes];
            
    //Zipcode de 100%Online
    Zip_Code__c zpcd = [SELECT Name, Franchise_area__c FROM Zip_Code__c WHERE Name =:'92800' LIMIT 1];
            

       for (Lead record : Trigger.new) {
           
                          
        if (record.PostalCode != null && record.FullAccess_OnlineOnly__c=='Full Access') {
           
                         
            for (Zip_Code__c zc : codes) {
                
               //List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
                                 
                
                if (record.PostalCode == zc.Name) {
                    record.WSEcenter__c = zc.Franchise_area__c;
                                         
                }
                
                    
            }
                                       
            }
                      
          
    } 
         
       for(Lead record : Trigger.new){
        
        if (record.PostalCode != null && record.FullAccess_OnlineOnly__c=='Online Only'){
            
            //record.PostalCode = null;
           // record.PostalCode = zpcd.Name;
            record.WSEcenter__c = zpcd.Franchise_area__c;
            
           }
        
    }    
            
           
}
```

}

TEST

```
@isTest
public class AffectationLeadBefore_TEST{
public static boolean ThrowException;

public static String Full_Access ;
public static String OnlineOnly;

public static String testLead1;
public static String testLead2;
public static String testLead3;

public static String acct1;


@isTest(seeAllData=true)
static void testWithLeadToFullAccess(){
    Full_Access = 'Full Access';
    
    Test.startTest();
    
    List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
    Lead ld0 = new Lead(FirstName = 'FNTESTZC000', LastName = 'LNTESTZC000', Company = 'N/A', PostalCode = '75012' );
    ld0.FullAccess_OnlineOnly__c = Full_Access;
    leads.add(ld0);
    
    Lead ld1 = new Lead(FirstName = 'FNTESTZC001', LastName = 'LNTESTZC001', Company = 'N/A', PostalCode = '75012' );
    ld1.FullAccess_OnlineOnly__c = Full_Access;
    leads.add(ld1);
    
    //insert leads;
    
    Lead ld = new Lead();
    ld.LastName = 'LuluTest';
    ld.FirstName= 'TestLulu';
    ld.FullAccess_OnlineOnly__c = 'Full Access';
    //insert ld;
    
    List<Zip_Code__c> zipCodes = new List<Zip_Code__c>(); 
    
    Zip_Code__c zpcd0 = new Zip_Code__c(Name = '00000', Commune__c = 'MACOMMUNETEST0');
    zipCodes.add(zpcd0);
    Zip_Code__c zpcd1 = new Zip_Code__c(Name = '00001', Commune__c = 'MACOMMUNETEST1');
    zipCodes.add(zpcd0);
    
    //insert zipCodes;
    //
    Zip_Code__c zipc = new Zip_Code__c();
    zipc.Name = '00000';
    zipc.Commune__c = 'TEST1';
    zipc.SYS_External_Id__c='00000_TEST1';
    
    insert zipc;
    
    
    
    zipCodes = [SELECT Name, Franchise_area__c  FROM Zip_Code__c WHERE Name=:zipCodes[0].Franchise_area__c ];
    
    System.assertEquals(ld0.WSEcenter__c, zpcd0.Franchise_area__c);
    
    Test.stopTest();
    
    
}


static testMethod void testWithLeadToFullAccess2(){
    
    List<Zip_Code__c> zipCodes = new List<Zip_Code__c>(); 
    
    Zip_Code__c zpcd0 = new Zip_Code__c(Name = '00010', Commune__c = 'MACOMMUNETEST10');
    zipCodes.add(zpcd0);
    Zip_Code__c zpcd1 = new Zip_Code__c(Name = '00011', Commune__c = 'MACOMMUNETEST11');
    zipCodes.add(zpcd1);
    
   // insert zipCodes;
   // 
   
    List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
   // Lead ld0 = new Lead(FirstName = 'FNTESTZC000', LastName = 'LNTESTZC000', Company = 'N/A', PostalCode = '00010');
    
    leads = [SELECT LastName, FullAccess_OnlineOnly__c FROM Lead WHERE PostalCode!=null AND FullAccess_OnlineOnly__c='Full Access'];
    
            if(leads.size()>0){
                Lead leadrecord = leads[0];
                System.assertEquals(leadrecord.WSEcenter__c , zpcd0.Franchise_area__c);
                
             }
    
}


@isTest(seeAllData=true)
static void testLeadTriggerViaDML1(){
    testLead1 = 'Test Lead1';
    Lead testLead = new Lead(FirstName = 'TestLeadZC01', LastName = 'ZCleadtest01', Company = 'N/A', PostalCode = '00001', FullAccess_OnlineOnly__c = 'Full Access', Status='Ouverte' );
    insert testLead;
    testLead = [select  LastName, Company from Lead where LastName =: testLead.LastName];
    //
    System.assertEquals(testLead.LastName, testLead1 ); 
    
   
}

@isTest(seeAllData=true)
static void testLeadTriggerViaDML2(){
    testLead2 = 'Test Lead2';
    Lead testLead = new Lead( FirstName = 'TestLeadZC02', LastName = 'ZCleadtest02', Company = 'N/A', PostalCode = '00002', FullAccess_OnlineOnly__c = 'Full Access', Status='Ouverte' );
    insert testLead;
    testLead = [select Id, LastName from Lead where Id = :testLead.Id];
    //
    System.assertEquals(testLead.LastName, testLead2);  
}


@isTest(seeAllData=true)
static void testLeadTriggerViaDML3(){
    testLead3 = 'Test Lead3';
    Lead testLead = new Lead(FirstName = 'TestLeadZC03',LastName = 'ZCleadtest03', Company = 'N/A',  PostalCode = '00003', FullAccess_OnlineOnly__c = 'Full Access', Status='Ouverte');
    insert testLead;
    testLead = [select Id, LastName from Lead where Id = :testLead.Id];
    //
    System.assertEquals(testLead.LastName, testLead3);  
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you using SeeAllData=true?

Comment: When I use 'static testMethod' and not @isTest(seeAllData=true) , I am at 50% coverage with For loops (Lead record: Trigger.new) not covered.

Comment: What is the best strategy to be able to have good test coverage ? And how to successfully cover for loops ? Thank you

Comment: When I use 'static testMethod' and not @isTest(seeAllData=true) , I get these errors : System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, AffectationLeadBefore: execution of BeforeInsert

caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Trigger.AffectationLeadBefore: line 23, column 1: []

Comment: Yes, during a unit test, you should create all the data you need for the test to pass. Insert a `Zip_Code__c` record that matches the expected criteria for the query.

Comment: Can you please explain to me why it throws me the error on System.assertEquals()? ' System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: ZCleadtest01, Actual: Test Lead1' ...Thank you

Comment: Hi Alluche, I'd really recommend you read not just the standard unit testing questions that have been linked to several of your posts but also the excellent resources that those questions link to on Trailhead and elsewhere. You need to start by defining your _code paths_ (sequences of logic that your code should execute based on input data), then write tests that create the input data and validate the outcome of that code path. Coverage is a _side effect_ of good tests. Again, see the linked resources for much more.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox

Comment: Thnaks @DavidReed, Could I have the related documentation please? Thank you

Comment: It is linked at the top of your question post.